# How to use MMS for audio in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mms

I did goggling about `MMS` in iPhone but I did not find much info on this,most of the findings are related to images. I would like to send audio using `MMS` in `iPhone` using `ios sdk`.Is it possible to do this?I have the following queries regarding `MMS`.

How to identify all the `MMS` audio files in `iPhone` using `iOS SDK`?

How to play `MMS` files in `iPhone` using `iOS SDK`?

Could some one help me in identifying these things !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MMS` as in Multimedia Messaging Service is not available for a developer in iOS.
Only the messages.app can send `MMS`, you can't access any data from the messages.app nor can you send an `MMS`.

The iOS SDK provides [Message UI Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MessageUI_Framework_Reference/_index.html) which allows you to send Email and Text messages. But the text messages are restricted to `SMS` only.

---

Update: iOS 7 now supports attachment.

```
 - (void)sendAudioFile:(NSURL)audioFilePath {
    if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendAttachments] &&
        [MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText] &&
        [MFMessageComposeViewController isSupportedAttachmentUTI:@"com.apple.coreaudio-​format"]) //.caf files
    { 
        NSLog(@"can send");

        MFMessageComposeViewController *message = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
        [message addAttachmentURL:audioFilePath withAlternateFilename:nil]; //.caf file
        message.messageComposeDelegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:message animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"cannot send");
    }
}
```

Comment: rchoenes: Thanks for quick response, but I saw this app in iTunes last updated for iOS 4 in sept 2010                                                        itunes.apple.com/us/app/get-mms/id304636819?mt=8. How this app is able to implement the MMS functionality? Are there are any new restrictions  in  the new iOS sdk

Comment: They probably provide there own MMS server, there are some third parties that provide this. But you as the developer will have to pay for the sending of the MMS. There is northing in the Apple iOS SDK that will allow you to send MMS.

Comment: Update: iOS 7 now supports attachment.

Comment: @Underdog I've added your edit to my answer, thnx for the update.

Comment: I am getting "cannot send" always, I am testing on Iphone 6plus, iOS 8.4.1. can any one help.