# Send attachments using sms/mms in iOS SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, sms, nsdata, attachment

In iOS 7, there is support for adding attachments in sms messages via third party applications.

I want to know:

1. What kind of files are supported as attachments? e.g. .png, .pdf etc.
2. Can I send NSData through an sms/mms message? e.g. .dat format
3. Would the recipient of these messages be able to open these attachments in third party applications using iOS's "Open In" feature?

Comment: have a look this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577565/how-to-attach-image-with-message-via-iphone-application

Comment: Thanks @Rushabh. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14434330/how-to-use-mms-for-audio-in-iphone) is more closer to what i need. But I also want to know if I can send NSData as well. Moreover, would the recipient be able to open that attachment in a third party application using Open-In

Answer (score 1):

The `MFMessageComposeViewController` wants the attachment to have the correct extension for the type of image you're uploading.
I verified by testing with a `PNG` file, and the following variations of adding the attachment data:

```
[messageController addAttachmentData:imgData typeIdentifier:@"public.data" filename:@"image"];
[messageController addAttachmentData:imgData typeIdentifier:@"public.data" filename:@"image.abc"];
[messageController addAttachmentData:imgData typeIdentifier:@"public.data" filename:@"image.png"];
```

Only the last option worked. 
I didn't need to change the `typeIdentifier`, although it probably would make sense to choose a UTI that matches the type of data.

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple [MFMessageComposeViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messageui/mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller) docs, you can do that by creating a MFMessageComposeViewController object, and add the attachment through the following functions:

```
func addAttachmentURL(URL, withAlternateFilename: String?)
```

*Attaches a specified file to the message.*

```
func addAttachmentData(Data, typeIdentifier: String, filename: String)
```

*Attaches arbitrary content to the message.*

(BTW you should check the **canSendAttachments** before you try to use those functions)