# Send a video to iMessage from custom app. Like an attachment

Tags: video, url-scheme, imessage

I want to send a video to directly iMessage(to iPhone contact) from own app. Is it possible?

If yes, how can I sent a video to iMessage contact?

URL Scheme would help in this case?

Comment: You can use UIActivityController to sahre content from your app to other apps

Comment: Does it help you out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24906712/send-attachments-using-sms-mms-in-ios-sdk